# naive filtering return wrong image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, convolution

I am trying to implement a convolution algorithm for process gradient filter such as SCHAR, SOBEL, or PREWITT using OpenCV.
OpenCV has already funcitons that do that very efficiently however they don't compute the resul in "one step".

E.g. for a sobel filter it must be processed in "three steps".
1) Sobel over the x axis (Sx) 
2) Sobel over the y axis (Sy)
3) association `(frequently 0.5 * sqrt(Sx^2 * Sy^2) )`

I wrote a naive algorithm for doing it in one time but it return a black image I don't really understand why.

```
cv::Mat kt = (cv::Mat1f(3,3)<<1,2,1,0,0,0,-1,-2,-1);
cv::Mat kt2 = kt.t();



  cv::Mat img = cv::imread("Lena.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);


img.convertTo(img, CV_32F);

// Extand the borders in order to simplify the border management.
cv::copyMakeBorder(img, img, 1,1,1,1, cv::BORDER_ISOLATED, cv::Scalar::all(0.));

// Get a sub region of the same size as the original image from the first row first column WITHOUT copy :) 
img = img(cv::Rect(1,1, img.cols-1, img.rows-1));

for(int r=0;r<img.rows;r++)
    for(int c=0;c<img.cols;c++)
    {
        float dx = 0.f;
        float dy = 0.f;

        for(int kr = -1; kr<=1;kr++)
            for(int kc = -1; kc<=1;kc++)
            {
                float value = img.at<float>(r+kr,c+kc);

                dx += 0.25f * value * kt.at<float>(kr+1, kc+1);
                dy += 0.25f * value * kt2.at<float>(kr+1, kc+1);
            }

        img.at<float>(r,c) = std::hypot(dx,dy); // sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2)
    }
```

The result is mostly a nan image. I do not really undestand why.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Note Schar's, Sobel's, and Prewitt's filters are separable filters. In that algorithm I do not use that property becau
se I am interrested to understand what is wrong with that simple algorithm.

Comment: I'm to tired to write a proper answer or read your code in detail, but after a quick look it appears to me that you both read and write from/to img. the output pixel value depends on the input pixels. if you change the input pixels you get wrong results for following output pixels... use a separate image for output. the rest I did not check sorry. have to sleep :)

Comment: Effectively it was simply that.
Thank you very much for your help :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As identify by @piglet my issue was finally quite simple.
I am trying to write the output in the image am working on.
Because the processing involve the neighbourhood it also influence the output.
A solution to this is simply to write the result of the processing in a different image than the one I am processing.

```
cv::Mat kt = (cv::Mat1f(3,3)<<1,2,1,0,0,0,-1,-2,-1);
cv::Mat kt2 = kt.t();



  cv::Mat img = cv::imread("Lena.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
  cv::Mat img2 = cv::Mat::zeros(img.size(),CV_32F);

img.convertTo(img, CV_32F);

// Extand the borders in order to simplify the border management.
cv::copyMakeBorder(img, img, 1,1,1,1, cv::BORDER_ISOLATED, cv::Scalar::all(0.));

// Get a sub region of the same size as the original image from the first row first column WITHOUT copy :) 
img = img(cv::Rect(1,1, img.cols-1, img.rows-1));

for(int r=0;r<img.rows;r++)
    for(int c=0;c<img.cols;c++)
    {
        float dx = 0.f;
        float dy = 0.f;

        for(int kr = -1; kr<=1;kr++)
            for(int kc = -1; kc<=1;kc++)
            {
                float value = img.at<float>(r+kr,c+kc);

                dx += 0.25f * value * kt.at<float>(kr+1, kc+1);
                dy += 0.25f * value * kt2.at<float>(kr+1, kc+1);
            }

        img2.at<float>(r,c) = std::hypot(dx,dy); // sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2)
    }
```